# How to remove horizontal lines in a table in html?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to remove horizontal lines from my HTML table

I have tried using CSS like `border-bottom` and border-top and set the value to 0  but that didn't change; whereas `border-right` and `border-left` working perfectly.

```css
tr {
  border-bottom: 0;
  /* border-bottom:none; */
}
```

```html
<table style="border:1px solid black;">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding:0px 15px 0px 65px;"><strong>Type</strong></td>
    <td style="padding:0px 15px 0px 20px; "><strong>Quantitiy</strong></td>
    <td style="padding:0px 15px 0px 0px;"><strong>price</strong></td>
    <td style="padding:0px 15px 0px 0px;"><strong>total price</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="type">
    <td style="padding:5px 15px 0px 65px;">{{type}}</td>
    <td style="padding:5px 15px 0px 20px;">{{meters}}</td>
    <td style="padding:5px 15px 0px 0px;">{{price}}</td>
    <td style="padding:5px 15px 0px opx;">{{price_total}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to remove those horizontal lines using CSS like `border-bottom` but failed.

i have just added psuedo code 
this is how actually my table looks like 
[image]

i want to remove those horiazontal line from cloth,shirt,pants straight away to the bottom for all the columns as well

Comment: `td{border-bottom-width:0;}` The top and bottom borders are on the cells, not on the rows. Please note that you demo code does not have borders. So what is your problem?

Comment: Which lines? There are no lines in your example.

Comment: @Oen44 don't forget that the browsers have default styles; some browsers might style tables with borders by default (I seem to remember IE does...at least older versions of IE).

Comment: i have added image to get an idea please have a look at it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
table, th, td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td{
    border:1px solid black;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

This should do the work

Answer (score 3):

Try to add style to `td` element. Not to `tr`.